# My matplotlib plotting function is not plotting one specific machine learning algorithm for some reason?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn

My code seems to be able to plot the results of all of the other classifiers of various machine learning algorithms except svc. svc seems to have the same output as the other code. I just can't see what can be possibly wrong. Any ideas as to what can be going on over here?
Here is the error:

> File "/Users/name/Google Drive/Rocks and
>   Minerals/rockssep/rockssep/nearest_neighbors.py", line 19, in 
>       x = plot_algorithms(algorithms,raw_data,nlabels,plot_vars,save=True,plot=False,pl=True,mat=False,pca=True)
>   File "/Users/name/Google Drive/Rocks and
>   Minerals/rockssep/rockssep/rocksep_utils.py", line 277, in
>   plot_algorithms
>       fig = plotAnalysisPCA(test_data,test_labels,y_pred,cmap,plot_vars,analysis_type,"Principle
>   Component Analysis of Classifier
>   Accuracy",pure_accuracy_rate,plot=False,cache=False,save=True,analysis_type=i.func_name.title().replace("_","
>   "))   File "/Users/name/Google Drive/Rocks and
>   Minerals/rockssep/rockssep/rocksep_utils.py", line 219, in
>   plotAnalysisPCA
>       ax.scatter(np.array(samples[0])[:,0],np.array(samples[0])[:,1],zs=np.array(samples[0])[:,2],c=cmap[x+1],marker
>   = '*') IndexError: too many indices for array

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy as st
from rocksep_utils import *

from sklearn.externals import joblib

cmap = {1:"red",2:"green",3:"blue",4:"orange"}
plot_vars = ["SIO2","AL2O3","MGO"]

# algorithms = [nearest_neighbors,random_forest,naive_base,ada,lda,qda,decision_tree,svc]
algorithms = [svc]
# print svc(raw_data,nlabels,4,"k_fold")
x = plot_algorithms(algorithms,raw_data,nlabels,plot_vars,save=True,plot=False,pl=True,mat=False,pca=True)
# joblib.dump(x['decision_tree'][5], 'decision_tree_model.pkl', compress=9)

# model_clone = joblib.load('decision_tree_model.pkl')
# model_clone.predict([41.44,4.45,6.75,44.69972])
```

here is the plotting code:

```
def plot_algorithms(algorithms,raw_data,nlabels,plot_vars,cmap={1:"red",2:"green",3:"blue",4:"orange"},save=False,plot=False,mat=True,pl=True,pca=False):
    values = {}
    for i in algorithms:
        pure_accuracy_rate,report,y_pred,test_labels,test_data,clf,cm,analysis_type = i(raw_data,nlabels,4,v_type=v_type)
        values[i.func_name] = [pure_accuracy_rate,report,y_pred,test_labels,test_data,clf,cm,analysis_type];
        pure_accuracy_rate = pure_accuracy_rate*100
        print analysis_type+"\n","Simple Accuracy: %.1f%%" % (pure_accuracy_rate)+"\n", report, cm
        if save:
            if pl:
                if pca:
                    fig = plotAnalysisPCA(test_data,test_labels,y_pred,cmap,plot_vars,analysis_type,"Principle Component Analysis of Classifier Accuracy",pure_accuracy_rate,plot=False,cache=False,save=True,analysis_type=i.func_name.title().replace("_"," "))
                else:   
                    fig = plotAnalysis(test_data,test_labels,y_pred,cmap,plot_vars,analysis_type,"3 Dimensional Demonstration of Classifier Accuracy",pure_accuracy_rate,plot=False,cache=False,save=True,analysis_type=i.func_name.title().replace("_"," "))
            if mat:
                show_confusion_matrix(cm,False,False,True,a_type=i.func_name.title().replace("_"," "),accuracy="%.1f%%" % (pure_accuracy_rate)) 
        elif plot:
            if pl:
                if pca:
                    fig = plotAnalysisPCA(test_data,test_labels,y_pred,cmap,plot_vars,analysis_type,"Principle Component Analysis of Classifier Accuracy",pure_accuracy_rate,plot=True,cache=False,save=False,analysis_type=i.func_name.title().replace("_"," "))
                else:
                    fig = plotAnalysis(test_data,test_labels,y_pred,cmap,plot_vars,analysis_type,"3 Dimensional Demonstration of Classifier Accuracy",pure_accuracy_rate,plot=True,cache=False,save=False,analysis_type=i.func_name.title().replace("_"," "))
            if mat:
                show_confusion_matrix(cm,True,False,False,a_type=i.func_name.title().replace("_"," "),accuracy="%.1f%%" % (pure_accuracy_rate)) 
    return values

def plotAnalysisPCA(test_data,test_labels,y_pred,cmap,plot_vars,type,title,accuracy,plot=True,cache=False,save=False,analysis_type=""):
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
    # x1,y1,z1 = [test_data[:,chemicals.index(x)] for x in plot_vars]

    hit_shapes = {True:"*",False:"o"}
    pca = PCA(n_components=3)
    x = pca.fit(test_data)
    raw_data_reduced = PCA.transform(x,test_data)
    x1,y1,z1 = [raw_data_reduced[:,x] for x in range(len(raw_data_reduced[0]))]
    r_samples = np.array([[np.array([x1[i],y1[i],z1[i],test_labels[i],y_pred[i]]) for i in range(len(test_labels)) if test_labels[i] == c] for c in range(1,5) ] ) 

    hit_mat = [y_pred[i] == test_labels[i] for i in range(len(test_labels))]
    hit_shapes_mat = [hit_shapes[i] for i in hit_mat]
    rock_colors = [cmap[x] for x in test_labels]
    for x in range(len(r_samples)):
        samples = [[i for i in r_samples[x] if i[3] == i[4]],[i for i in r_samples[x] if i[3] != i[4]]]
        ax.scatter(np.array(samples[0])[:,0],np.array(samples[0])[:,1],zs=np.array(samples[0])[:,2],c=cmap[x+1],marker = '*')
        ax.scatter(np.array(samples[1])[:,0],np.array(samples[1])[:,1],zs=np.array(samples[1])[:,2],c=cmap[x+1],marker = 'o')
    # for i in range(len(hit_shapes_mat)):
    #   ax.scatter(x1[i], y1[i], zs=z1[i], c=rock_colors[i], marker=hit_shapes_mat[i],s=50)

    proxy_labels = [matplotlib.lines.Line2D([0],[0], linestyle="none", c='black', marker = 'o'), matplotlib.lines.Line2D([0],[0], linestyle="none", c='black', marker = '*')]
    for i in rock_types.values():
        proxy_labels.append(matplotlib.lines.Line2D([0],[0], linestyle="none", c=cmap[i], marker = 'o'))
    ax.legend(proxy_labels, ['Incorrectly Classified', 'Correctly Classified']+rock_types.keys(), numpoints = 1,prop={'size':6},bbox_to_anchor=(1.1, .1))
    ax.set_xlabel("PCA Component 0")
    ax.set_ylabel("PCA Component 1")
    ax.set_zlabel("PCA Component 2")
    ax.set_title(analysis_type+": "+title+":\n Overall Accuracy: "+"%.1f%%" % accuracy)
    ax.view_init(elev=57,azim=82)
    if plot == True:
        plt.show()
    if cache == True:
        plt.savefig("./matplotlib_cache/pca_{}_figure{}.png".format(analysis_type,time.time()))
    if save == True:
        plt.savefig("./matplotlib_save/pca_{}_figure{}.png".format(analysis_type,time.time())) 
    return fig
```

and here is the function for the svc algorithm that is not working for some reason, it is structured the same way as all of the other algorithms

```
def svc(data,labels,n,v_type):
    train_data,train_labels,test_data,test_labels = split_data(data,labels,v_type)

    clf = SVC(kernel="linear", C=0.025)
    clf.fit(train_data, train_labels)
    y_pred = clf.predict(test_data)
    pure_accuracy_rate = len([y_pred[x] for x in range(len(y_pred)) if y_pred[x] == test_labels[x]])/float(len(test_labels))
    report = classification_report(y_pred, test_labels, target_names=rock_names)
    cm = confusion_matrix(test_labels, y_pred)
    return pure_accuracy_rate,report,y_pred,test_labels,test_data,clf,cm,"SVC"
```

and this is how I split my data into a training and testing set:

```
def split_data(raw_data,labels,type):
    if v_type == "split":
        train_data,test_data,train_labels,test_labels = raw_data[0:int(len(raw_data)/2)],raw_data[int(len(raw_data)/2):],nlabels[0:int(len(nlabels)/2)],nlabels[int(len(nlabels)/2):]
    elif v_type == "c_validation":
        train_data,test_data,train_labels,test_labels = cross_validation.train_test_split(raw_data, nlabels, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)
    elif v_type =="k_fold":
        train_data,train_labels,test_data,test_labels =  s_k_fold(raw_data,nlabels)
    return train_data,train_labels,test_data,test_labels
```

When i try to use pca, it fails at svc, if I print out samples i get:

> Nearest Neighbors Simple Accuracy: 79.4%
>                precision    recall  f1-score   support
>
> ```
>  DUNITE       0.65      0.75      0.70        32 HARZBURGITE       0.77      0.76      0.76       143  LHERZOLITE       0.86      0.84      0.85       242    WEHRLITE       0.42      0.53      0.47        15
> ```
>
> avg / total       0.80      0.79      0.80       432
>
> Random Forest Simple Accuracy: 78.7%
>                precision    recall  f1-score   support
>
> ```
>  DUNITE       0.68      0.60      0.63        42 HARZBURGITE       0.79      0.73      0.76       151  LHERZOLITE       0.83      0.88      0.85       224    WEHRLITE       0.47      0.60      0.53        15
> ```
>
> avg / total       0.79      0.79      0.79       432
>
> Naive Base Simple Accuracy: 70.6%
>                precision    recall  f1-score   support
>
> ```
>  DUNITE       0.27      0.56      0.36        18 HARZBURGITE       0.87      0.59      0.70       208  LHERZOLITE       0.71      0.89      0.79       188    WEHRLITE       0.32      0.33      0.32        18
> ```
>
> avg / total       0.75      0.71      0.71       432
>
> ADA Boost Simple Accuracy: 78.2%
>                precision    recall  f1-score   support
>
> ```
>  DUNITE       0.70      0.63      0.67        41 HARZBURGITE       0.75      0.73      0.74       143  LHERZOLITE       0.83      0.88      0.85       223    WEHRLITE       0.58      0.44      0.50        25
> ```
>
> avg / total       0.78      0.78      0.78       432
>
> LDA Simple Accuracy: 77.5%
>                precision    recall  f1-score   support
>
> ```
>  DUNITE       0.51      0.79      0.62        24 HARZBURGITE       0.66      0.73      0.70       127  LHERZOLITE       0.91      0.80      0.85       268    WEHRLITE       0.47      0.69      0.56        13
> ```
>
> avg / total       0.80      0.78      0.78       432
>
> /Users/Avi/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py:1327:
>   DeprecationWarning: Implicitly casting between incompatible kinds. In
>   a future numpy release, this will raise an error. Use casting="unsafe"
>   if this is intentional.   u, s, vt = gufunc(a, signature=signature,
>   extobj=extobj)
>   /Users/Avi/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py:1327:
>   DeprecationWarning: Implicitly casting between incompatible kinds. In
>   a future numpy release, this will raise an error. Use casting="unsafe"
>   if this is intentional.   u, s, vt = gufunc(a, signature=signature,
>   extobj=extobj)
>   /Users/Avi/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py:1327:
>   DeprecationWarning: Implicitly casting between incompatible kinds. In
>   a future numpy release, this will raise an error. Use casting="unsafe"
>   if this is intentional.   u, s, vt = gufunc(a, signature=signature,
>   extobj=extobj)
>   /Users/Avi/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py:1327:
>   DeprecationWarning: Implicitly casting between incompatible kinds. In
>   a future numpy release, this will raise an error. Use casting="unsafe"
>   if this is intentional.   u, s, vt = gufunc(a, signature=signature,
>   extobj=extobj) QDA Simple Accuracy: 75.5%
>                precision    recall  f1-score   support
>
> ```
>  DUNITE       0.35      0.72      0.47        18 HARZBURGITE       0.83      0.65      0.73       179  LHERZOLITE       0.79      0.86      0.82       217    WEHRLITE       0.58      0.61      0.59        18
> ```
>
> avg / total       0.78      0.75      0.76       432
>
> Decision Tree Simple Accuracy: 78.9%
>                precision    recall  f1-score   support
>
> ```
>  DUNITE       0.51      0.86      0.64        22 HARZBURGITE       0.78      0.72      0.75       151  LHERZOLITE       0.86      0.84      0.85       241    WEHRLITE       0.58      0.61      0.59        18
> ```
>
> avg / total       0.80      0.79      0.79       432
>
> /Users/Avi/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/metrics.py:1905:
>   UserWarning: The precision and recall are equal to zero for some
>   labels. fbeta_score is ill defined for those labels [4].
>   average=None) SVC Simple Accuracy: 78.0%
>                precision    recall  f1-score   support
>
> ```
>  DUNITE       0.57      0.91      0.70        23 HARZBURGITE       0.80      0.72      0.76       155  LHERZOLITE       0.86      0.81      0.83       253    WEHRLITE       0.00      0.00      0.00         1
> ```
>
> avg / total       0.82      0.78      0.80       432
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/Users/Avi/Google
>   Drive/Rocks and Minerals/rockssep/rockssep/nearest_neighbors.py", line
>   19, in 
>       x = plot_algorithms(algorithms,raw_data,nlabels,plot_vars,save=True,pl=True,mat=True,plot=False,pca=True,directory="./figures/test")   File "/Users/Avi/Google Drive/Rocks and
>   Minerals/rockssep/rockssep/rocksep_utils.py", line 279, in
>   plot_algorithms
>       fig = plotAnalysisPCA(test_data,test_labels,y_pred,cmap,plot_vars,analysis_type,"Principle
>   Component Analysis of Classifier
>   Accuracy",pure_accuracy_rate,plot=False,cache=False,save=True,analysis_type=i.func_name.title().replace("_","
>   "),)   File "/Users/Avi/Google Drive/Rocks and
>   Minerals/rockssep/rockssep/rocksep_utils.py", line 221, in
>   plotAnalysisPCA
>       ax.scatter(np.array(samples[0])[:,0],np.array(samples[0])[:,1],zs=np.array(samples[0])[:,2],c=cmap[x+1],marker
>   = '*') IndexError: too many indices for array [Finished in 6.2s with exit code 1] [shell_cmd: python -u "/Users/Avi/Google Drive/Rocks and
>   Minerals/rockssep/rockssep/nearest_neighbors.py"] [dir:
>   /Users/Avi/Google Drive/Rocks and Minerals/rockssep/rockssep] [path:
>   /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]

Comment: can you also provide some data samples which at least will be able to plot with? To many undefined names here that makes others very difficult to debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too many codes and undefined names here makes it really hard to reproduce your problem. However having a quick glance, here seems to be where it goes wrong:

```
samples = [[i for i in r_samples[x] if i[3] == i[4]],[i for i in r_samples[x] if i[3] != i[4]]]
ax.scatter(np.array(samples[0])[:,0],np.array(samples[0])[:,1],zs=np.array(samples[0])[:,2],c=cmap[x+1],marker = '*')
        ax.scatter(np.array(samples[1])[:,0],np.array(samples[1])[:,1],zs=np.array(samples[1])[:,2],c=cmap[x+1],marker = 'o')
```

`samples` is 2d like this `[[1,2,3],[2,3,4]]`, and `np.array(samples[0])[:,0]` will throw **IndexError: too many indices for array** as you are trying get a "tuple" from the list. `samples` array in your case is incorrectly structure.

`samples` should be in this form `[[[x,y],[x,y],...[x,y]], [[x,y],[x,y],...[x,y]]]`.

You should restructure `samples` and see if this helps eliminate the error.

Comment: but it works for every type of analysis except for svc

Comment: its because your other analysis use another set of data. the data structure is different. Its hard to tell without some of your samples.

Comment: would it be against the rules for me to send you a link to the entirety of my code?

Comment: is your code hosted in a public repo? if your code can be shared to the public you may edit your post and add the link.

Comment: but in your case, I think its better to show how you construct your data or simply show some data samples. so we get a better understanding of what you were trying to do

Comment: ok here is how my data looks like:
ROCK NAME |SIO2 |TIO2| AL2O3|   CR2O3|  FEOT|   CAO|    MGO|    MNO|    K2O|    NA2O|   P2O5|  
WEHRLITE    |45.42| 0.17|   2.57|   0.32|   11.3384|    7.54|   31.93|  0.17|   0.01|   0.24|   0.01|

Comment: um... those are not helping much. can you post a link perhaps with your code and what data you're using, if possible? I'm going out soon and will take a closer look and try to pin down where it went wrong tonight.

Comment: sure thanks for taking so much for you time to help me

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwnTJgNfKPBpVmpMQ3BlWmQ1OVE/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwnTJgNfKPBpOF94V0MzcFI0MG8/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwnTJgNfKPBpVWJqazJGbFJ2NmM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @EvanMosseri, I have taken a quick look of the codes. Unfortunately there are still many missing pieces. That said, can you generate what `r_samples` and `samples` are?

Comment: r_samples contains three components, the actual classification, and the predicted classification for the test_dataset. samples is breaking up the x,y,z into a dataset of correctly classified and a dataset of incorrectly classified

Comment: how's that `samples` dataset looks like, is this like => `[[[x,y,z],[x1,y1,z1],...],[[x,y,z],[x1,y1,z1],...],...]`?

Comment: samples contains [[correctly classified data],[incorrectly classified data]]

Comment: honestly, I am not entirely sure. but it works for every other analysis type as you can see in the error message that I just added

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help much further, as I cannot reproduce the problem without some sample data. However the error you got has definitely something to do with your incorrectly structured `samples` array.

Comment: oh sorry i forgot to include the sample data. here you go:
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BwnTJgNfKPBpV0tRdkwtQVZzM3M&usp=sharing

Comment: but if you are done, I want to thank you for all of the time that you spent helping me

Comment: no worries mate. I may take a final look of your notebook and see if I can dig out more information today or tomorrow. Will keep you posted.